# Get currently connected users information in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How can I get count of currently connected (online) users to my Oracle database?

I am using below query but I don't believe this is giving correct information because in my own system I have multiple In house applications open that are connected to the database but they are not being listed here. How can I get the reliable information.

```
SELECT sess.status, sess.osuser,sess.schemaname, sess.username, sess.terminal,sess.program,sess.type,sess.module, sess.logon_time, sess.sql_id,sess.service_name
FROM v$session sess, 
     v$sql sql 
WHERE sql.sql_id(+) = sess.sql_id 
AND sess.type = 'USER'
order by sess.status;
```

Comment: Just because you have multiple applications accessing the database does not preclude the possibility that some of them share a user for accessing the Oracle database.

Comment: `v$session` **will** show all open connections. Unrelated but: you should really get used to the modern explicit `OUTER JOIN` syntax instead of using the old implicit joins and Oracle's proprietary `(+)` syntax (even Oracle recommends that)